# Publish BOT from Visual Studio 2017

Tags: botframework

We are receiving an error due to file length of our solution where we’re seeing the following nested files: obj\Release\package\packagetmp\obj\Release\package\packagetmp… when publishing our solution.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same issue with one project. I'm not sure of the cause. You should be able to remove everything under packagetmp and rebuild and publish.